# Change text $this->__('Choose an option...') in template

Tags: configurable-product, template, localisation

There are a number of changes that I would like to make to the theme but I give just one here as an example. Where the dropdown says 'Choose an Option', I  like to be polite and ask users to 'Please Choose an Option'.

So, I enable template path hints and block name hints. The block name hint in the image obscures the full path to the file which is...

`frontend/default/paul_overrides/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`

[image]

When I get to `configurable.phtml` there is very little there...

[image]

I do notice the ability to change 'Choose an Option' but when I did change it, it doesn't change on the site. So I don't understand why, it must be getting that from somewhere else.

Also the block name hints. So i have `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`
What does that refer to and how does that help me find the code that is creating the html?

---

**Update**

Thank You fschmengler.

I created translate.csv in my child theme 'paul_overrides', I inserted the line you suggested into this and also the file highlighted below to make sure i would catch it. Unfortunately neither worked and I am still getting the original display on the dropdown.

[image]

Any ideas?

Must say, I'm very surprised at magento, it is hailed as being easy to modify but if this example is anything to go by it seems anything but easy.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Actually, "easy to modify" is not how I would describe Magento, you *can* modify pretty much but the learning curve is steep

Comment: Did you clean the cache?

Comment: Thank You fschmengler, I have cache disabled in during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change texts in the `phtml` templates, use translation instead.

In your case, you want to change the return value of `$this->__('Choose an option...')`. When the dropdown is populated dynamically with JavaScript, the same translation is used again (and this is why changing the value only in this template did not work).

The block type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable` is the class that is used to render this template and you can tell from it that it's in the `Mage_Catalog` module.

With this information, you can change the translation in your theme:

### How to change the translation

1. Open the file `app/design/[your_package]/[your_theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv` or create it if it does not exist.
2. Add this line:

   ```
    "Mage_Catalog::Choose an option...","Please choose an option..."
   ```

This will tell Magento to use `"Please choose an option..."` instead of `"Choose an option..."` everywhere in the `Mage_Catalog` module.

---

Alternatively you can use the inline translation feature, as explained here: http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/ - this will store your changed translations in the database instead.

It's easy to use but you cannot search for the texts in the code base anymore and it's harder to migrate/deploy the translations to another system. So I prefer using translation files but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

This drop is generated by JavaScript,json object.

If it option value,Choose an Option text is coming from

**For Custom option:**
- Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select

- js/varien/product.js make dropdown for custom option product

**For configurable product option:**

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable


<?php

class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract
{
 public function getJsonConfig()
    {.....
        $config = array(
            'attributes'        => $attributes,
            'template'          => str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
            'basePrice'         => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())),
            'oldPrice'          => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getPrice())),
            'productId'         => $currentProduct->getId(),
            'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
            'taxConfig'         => $taxConfig
        );

        .......
    }


}
```

You need to change  on this class for the text.

`js/varien/configurable.js` make `dropdown` for configurable product

Comment: Or use translation.

Comment: Yes. It really good idea.. But whenever it have mule varien that time createvisdue

Comment: If there's an answer in there somewhere I can't find it!

Answer (score 0):

Really easy way to change this is to log into admin goto Systen->Config->Developer->Translate Inline. Enable for front end for what every view you want then go to your product page.

Now simply find the tiny book icon and click on it, from here you can quickly and easily change this text to whatever you want without touching a line of code.