# Change text from "Choose file" to "Browse"

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, product-view

We created custom option for product from backend, so in product view page its displaying like below

[image]

we want to **rename text "choose file" & "No file chosen"**

using template path hints, i got file : `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml`

if i delete below code , its going to delete those texts. but i want to rename it.

```
<input type="file" name="<?php echo $_fileName; ?>" class="product-custom-option
        <?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?>"
        <?php echo $_fileExists ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" />
```

i changed text in **app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv** file ,
 but it didn't worked for me....

as @Amit Bera suggested in this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75236/change-text-this-choose-an-option-in-template) , i tried in

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php ,
```

but here these texts not available. so how i can rename those texts ?

Comment: Please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file

Comment: May be this can help you:



<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('fileID').click(); return false;" />Browse</a>
<input type="file" id="fileID" style="visibility: hidden;" />

Comment: Thanks again @ChiragRajput , I found solution , but its really strange that magento don't have control on these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use label and decorate it because this text very with every browser

```
<label for="files" class="button">your desire text</label>
<input type="file" id="files" style="display:none" name="<?php echo $_fileName; ?>" class="product-custom-option
            <?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?>"
            <?php echo $_fileExists ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" />
```

Comment: update with this code you add label part not file part

Comment: That's really fantastic information that it depends on browser, but its really strange that magento don't have control on these things.

Comment: There's nothing strange in this ... Browsers are responsible for the prompt linked to your computer, not your website. Your website is only integrated in your browser.

Comment: @JulienLachal i was waiting for your comment ;)

Comment: @QaisarSatti, pls help on this -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210021/image-import-gets-stuck-in-magento-on-live-server